# How does a GTK callback function discover its own widget pointer in C?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I am writing a small editor in C/GTK+3. All the apps are initialized in their own C files: `app.c`, `notebook.c`, &c. (Unlike all the GTK tutorials online which, annoyingly, opaquely, do this all in one file.) I created `init()` functions to create the widgets and subwidgets. (I haven't subclassed anything yet, as doing this semi-procedurally was stretching my skills already.)

I enabled HANDLES_OPEN and created the `open()` callback to catch the signal, but now that I have the GFile, I need to tell the GTKNotebook widget to open a new tab with a widget to view the file. But how? My options:

1. Global variables. I would rather not.
2. I can drill down with `get_children()` until I find the (only) GTKNotebook widget. This seems silly, wasteful, and subject to future breakage as I continue to work on it.
3. I can pass a struct down with the init requests, copy the needed widget pointers into it, and then pass that in custom signals so that the callback functions know which widget they are.
4. Does properly subclassing my GTKNotebook, and adding the callback to it, allow me to call some `get_self()` function for the widget's own pointer?

Or am I missing something even more basic? Thank you in advance.

-p

**ETA:** @n-1-8e9-wheres-my-share-m: the code is:

main.c:

```
...
app_main = gtk_application_new ("com.github.somercet.gvis", G_APPLICATION_HANDLES_OPEN);
g_signal_connect (app_main, "activate", G_CALLBACK (on_app_main_activate), NULL);
g_signal_connect (app_main, "open", G_CALLBACK (on_app_main_open), NULL);
stat = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app_main), argc, argv);
...
```

app.c:

```
void on_app_main_open (GApplication *app_main, GFile **files, gint nf, const gchar *hint)
{
    win_init (app_main);

    for (i = 0; i < nf; i++)
        nbook_filetab_open (files[i]);  
}
```

win.c:

```
void win_init (GApplication *app_main)
{
    ...
    nbook_main = nbook_main_init ();
    gtk_box_pack_start (box_main, nbook_main, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
    gtk_widget_show_all (win_main);
}
```

notebook.c:

```
GtkWidget * nbook_main_init (void)
{
    ...
    nbook_main = (GTK_NOTEBOOK (gtk_notebook_new ());
    page = gtk_notebook_append_page (nbook_main, sw_flist, lbl_flist);
    npage = gtk_notebook_get_nth_page (nbook_main, page);
    gtk_notebook_set_tab_reorderable (nbook_main, npage, FALSE);
    gtk_notebook_set_tab_pos (nbook_main, GTK_POS_TOP);

    return GTK_WIDGET (nbook_main);
}
```

So far, so good. But now `on_app_main_open()` needs to call `gtk_notebook_append_page(nbook_main, ...)` to open a new tab and to attach an edit window to it. So how does `on_app_main_open()` know what the pointer is to `nbook_main`? I have two choices, I think:

1. Procedurally: I can create `void nbook_filetab_open (GFile *location)` in `notebook.c` and use a static global variable to copy the pointer into `nbook_filetab_open()`. I know this is a least-approved method.
2. Object-oriented: I can subclass all my code properly (which I will have to learn how to do), and then create ``nbook_filetab_open()`as a registered callback. BUT: if/when I do that, what is the canonical GTK way to give`nbook_filetab_open()`the widget pointer to`nbook_main```?
3. Or is the accepted GTK way just to grovel through the child widgets until I find a GtkNotebook widget that looks like the right one?

Thanks for your patience, this is the most ambitious thing I've ever coded. Especially in C.

Comment: Can you show some code? It is difficult to say what you are doing wrong without having a look at what you are doing.

Comment: @8e9 replied, thanks.

Comment: I am out of my depth here, but to my untrained eye it looks like some super ultra genius developer decided that this particular callback doesn't need an application user data parameter that every callback should have, because screw everybody. *That* would be the proper procedural method (not global/static data). For the method 3, see [this example](https://github.com/ToshioCP/Gtk4-tutorial/blob/main/gfm/sec15.md#activate-and-open-handler). Disclaimer, I don't really know what I'm talking about.

Comment: Yes. I think I will make the return value a pointer to a struct of two widget pointers: one for the main widget; and one for the sub-widget that actually needs to talk to other program parts. As for the super-geniuses, well, this ```open()``` command comes from the launch command line, so I can't blame them for *that*. The alarmingly incomplete official GTK tutorials, though... :-P

Answer (score 0):

Subclass. It's absolutely ok. You can subclass `GtkApplicationWindow`, store a pointer to `Notebook` in the private section and add open handler. On `GtkApplication's "open"` signal you can iterate over the windows with `gtk_application_get_windows()` and when you find appropriate window (if your application allows more than 1) call the handler.

```c
/* Application window subclass */
typedef struct _MyApplicationWindowPrivate {
    GtkNotebook *nb;
} 

boolean
my_applicatio_window_handle_open(MyApplicationWindow *self, GFile *f // etc) {
    g_return_val_if_fail(MY_IS_APPLICATION_WINDOW(self), FALSE);

    GtkWidget *subpage = my_custom_widget_for_gfile(f);

    gtk_notebook_append(self->priv->nb, subpage...);
    return TRUE;
}

/* "open" handler */
void on_app_main_open(GtkApplication * app, args) {
    GList *app_windows = gtk_application_get_windows(app);
    GList *link;
    for (link = app_windows; link != NULL; link = link->next) {
        if (my_application_window_handle_open(link->data, args))
            return TRUE;
    }

}
```

Don't forget to store `nb` in private section during construction of `MyApplicationWindow`.

Comment: Once I create a subclass, is there a way for the receiving widget to refer to itself in the callback function? ty for replying! Subclassing fills me with dread, as I learned procedural C, and using it in an OO way is difficult.

Comment: Almost all gtk signals have `void* userdata` parameter, which will be passed during signal emission. So you can do something like this: `g_signal_connect(self->priv->some_obj, "signal-name", callback, self)` where self is pointer to the object, priv is private section. This will lead to callback being called this way: `callback(some_obj, self)`

Comment: Thank you, I will get some sleep for now and try it. Wish me luck. ;-)

Comment: Okay, I managed to get one of my seven files (so far) converted to a GvisApp subclass, and it compiled without warnings/errors! I think I will pass the App object down the init functions, until it reaches all the subwidgets that will need to talk to it. Then all the top program logic can go in there. On to the other six...

Comment: Ugh. I converted the files, and am now hitting a new snag. So my subclass of GtkApplicationWindow needs to handle open() and activate() signals. But it also needs the args ("com.github.somercet.gvis", G_APPLICATION_HANDLES_OPEN). Gnome's explains under their example "your_class_new": "// Change/Add nothing here, use class/instance init" and "return g_object_new (GVIS_TYPE_APPLICATION, NULL);" ... It says nothing about how to chain up *_new() arguments... I get various errors, first was GLib-GIO: "This application can not open files." Now what? :-(

Comment: Can you give a link to the example you are referring?

Comment: I ended up asking in IRC gtk.gnome. They pointed out that I had to read the GtkApp source to copy its new() arguments into my subclass: application-id and the flags. This is all very dispiriting. I'm beginning to wish Miguel de Icaza had never been born, and we had all jumped to GNU Openstep and Objective C.

Comment: But, my original problem still stands: I have three widgets that need to speak to each other: a Notebook (for multiple files), an Entry (for user commands), and a TreeView to list open buffers. But the TV is a page in the Notebook, so its new() is not in the Win.c file. I can get around that, BUT: when the user hits Enter and a command enters the system, it needs to know WHO gets the parsed command! I can send down the WIN or APP pointer through the new() function, I suppose I need to set it as a property.

Comment: So what's the problem? I don't know how your system is supposed to find destination for a command. Whether it's a command's prefix, or currently visible page or something else. Anyway, the original problem involved handling of "open" signal, but now you mention Entry for commands. Feel free to ask another question. This question was about finding GtkNotebook. I've updated the answer a bit